# Android Service that monitors user activity

Tags: android, android-service

Is it possible for a background service to log every action of the user on his device? I just want to check if our devices are vulnerable to such actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. But depending on what your app wants to monitor, you don't need to run a `Service` just to constantly monitor the user's actions. All you need is a `BroadcastReceiver` that listens to `Intent`s fired by the system when specific phone events occur.

For example, I once built a mobile app that logs all the user's sent SMSes, detects incoming SMS, incoming and outgoing calls, and bytes of data sent and received over 3G and WiFi. Shameless plug, I've posted some tutorials on how to do it in my website: http://www.mattquiros.com/blog

Comment: oops sorry I'm currently transferring hosts, will be up soon ;)

Comment: I want to start a service at boot up and log every user interaction till the phone is locked...and I want to restart the service once the phone is unlocked and so on...Ur website is down..hope it goes up soon..

Comment: In that case, register a service in your manifest and include an intent-filter for `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`. As for when the phone becomes locked, I don't know what event is fired when that happens so you're gonna have to Google that yourself. ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help bro..I know about the boot completed intent and all that stuff.. I just wanted to know if I can log every user interaction on the device like what keys the user has pressed, whom he has called etc...And if it is possible isn't it a security threat

Comment: It is possible to detect even the key presses. Is it a security risk? Depends on how you look at it. Before your app is installed in the user's device, a dialog appears listing all the permissions your app needs (you define these permissions in the `AndroidManifest.xml`). If the user proceeds with the installation, then that means the user has explicitly granted you those permissions, for example, to read the key presses and log the other events. It's really a "risk" only if the user is stupid enough to grant those permissions to an untrusted developer.

Comment: I have made the tutorials available. If my response helped, feel free to select it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also monitor the other way. Looking at the Browser class and monitoring processes and what tasks are running using ActivityManager.